# Getting an answer related to exponential

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I express $\omega^2 - 2 \omega \cos \theta +1 = 0 $ ?

I tried to use this notation $cos( \theta ) + i \sin( \theta ) = e^{i \theta}$ .

I supposed to get $\omega = e^{\pm   i \theta}$ but I didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use quadratic formula
$$\omega=\frac{2\cos\theta\pm\sqrt{4\cos^2\theta-4}}{2}$$
$$=\cos\theta\pm\sqrt{-\sin^2\theta}$$
$$=\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta$$
$$=e^{\pm i\theta}$$